# What is the solution for character cannot mapped error..?

Tags: android

An error message is appeared when i was trying to create an app in malayalam.What can i do to solve this.

Error:Some characters cannot mappped using "Cp 1252"character encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your text encoding to UTF-8.

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences, select General -> Workspace. From the Text file encoding dropdown, select UTF-8.

do as follows:

download AnjaliOldLipi.ttf font.that's the malayalam font .search google for the file.
under your android assets folder create if not exist the folder fonts: assets/fonts/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf

then display texts this way were textview is a TextView: textview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf"))